# Cordova - eventListener / executeScript for _blank & _system target

Tags: ios, cordova, pdf

I have inAppBrowser (displaying web view in my application - ios). For that, I use inAppBrowser plugin for Cordova. If I'm accessing a pdf url, i change my target from _blank to _system. The problem comes now: I do have 2 events: loadstart and loadstop. If I'm accessing loadstart to call _system target, behind, after loadstop is loaded, view will be changed. 
My target is: I want my application to be target: _blank almost whole time. After I access a pdf url (example: http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf) my application want to have target: _system (only on pdf) and after I go from web, application shoult be untouched (no url changed).
I will let my code here. Thanks..

```
var inAppBrowserRef;
var app = {

initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

onLoadStart: function(event) {
  if (event.url.length > 3 && event.url.substr(event.url.length - 3).toLowerCase() == 'pdf') {
    inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: 'history.go(0);' });
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open(event.url, '_system');
  }
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    console.log('Starting InAppBrowser');
    inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.ro/', '_blank', 'location=no');
    inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', this.onLoadStart);
    inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
      inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: 'document.body.classList.add("app");' });
    });
    },
};
app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to capture the IAB's `exit` event not `loadstop`. By doing this, when the user closes the google window the PDF will be displayed.

Your code will start to load google into the `blank` window, and when loading is started will try to kick off a `system` browser for the PDF. If our experience is anything to go by, this will crash as opening the `system` window will alter the state of the `blank` window. If you need these to run side-by-side you're likely to be in a world of pain, we had to fork the IAB to get this to work amongst other things - our use case is pretty complex though.

Comment: The google url, is an example. On IAB side, it's working perfectly, until i have a pdf url in front. When i access it, it opens the browser (_system), but when i close it, i have a problem. my IAB is going on that url too. I want to block the page on IAB side, and doing stuffs only with PDF on Browser side. Aaand, after i finish with my Browser side, by going back, on IAB (_blank) i want to be able to access again the pdf in same conditions..

Comment: On the other side, maybe it is possible somehow to read that pdf, with a cordova plugin.. but i tried file opener 2, and didn't worked for me, for URLs... And I will tell you what exactly i want.. All what i want is to be able to read that PDF, and to go back yo my IOS App. If i simple access a PDF url right now, it opens, but i dont have any BACK BUTTON, And i dont know how to make that possible..

Comment: I doubt it's related to the pdf - if you use another URL I suspect you'll get the same behaviour. We had massive problems opening with _system IAB while having another (_blank) instance open and active, the native code for the _system browser interacts with the code for the existing window (in our case crashes), I'm guessing this is the source of your _blank window navigating.

Comment: Initially we arranged it so that the _blank browser closed when opening the system one. You can take a look at our fork - https://github.com/tombolaltd/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser if you want to keep the browser open.

Comment: I've just seen your other question - The reason you don't have a wokring  back button on your system window is because, when you

cordova.InAppBrowser.open(event.url, '_system');

This creates a new window with no history other than than the current page.

Comment: Is there any chance to read a PDF URL, with a plugin, and display any back button? My code looks like this right now: https://postimg.org/image/r9mzhttbr/ and in the right you can see how my app looks like. No buttons :(

Comment: Don't really understand.. I m sorry because i'm newbie in IOS apps, but... can you help me with any solution @ my problem..? hmm..

Comment: I think we might have our wires crossed - in your code you have toolbar=no, this switches off the toolbar. Try:

toolbar=yes

Comment: I know what are you saying. But i want it only for PDF files. I put a condition to check if it's pdf, and now toolbar is shown on pdf opening BUT when i go back, it doesn't hide....

Comment: It won't hide on back - there is nothing to "back" to when you open "_system" It's a new browser/tab instance. You can't display the back button after you've opened the IAB with the toolbar open either - it just won't let you.